# App Certificaion fails with: API FreeAddrInfoEx in ws2_32.dll is not supported for this application type

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-store, zxing.net

I created a very simple Xamarin Forms App which uses `ZXing.Net.Mobile` and `HttpClient` (the app scans a bar-/QR-code and sends it to a server). This app was successfully released in the App Store and the Play Store, but when uploading it to the Microsoft Store the Certification fails with the following message on each architecture (x86, x64, ARM, ARM64) in the "Supported API test" section:

> API FreeAddrInfoEx in ws2_32.dll is not supported for this application type. MyApp.UWP.dll calls this API.

I do not know what causes this, but I suspect ZXing as this is the only third-Party library I did not use in a published app before.
Does anybody know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this is a problem with the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` package v6.2.2 (see https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/924). Downgrading to v6.1.9 seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Derive from the [blog](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/20/net-native-what-it-means-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-developers/#q3wZyOopSZpDbXyv.97):

When you run the WACK on a UWP app that did not go through this compilation process, you will get a not-so-trivial failure. It will look something like:

*API ExecuteAssembly in uwphost.dll is not supported for this application type. App.exe calls this API.*

.......

The fix is to make sure you are creating your packages properly, and running WACK on the right one. If you follow these [packaging guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh454036(v=vs.140)), you should never encounter this issue.

Please pay attention the part:[Before packaging your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh454036(v=vs.140)#before-packaging-your-app) and check your app as required.